# angular js duplicate value push in to array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to stop duplicate value insert to my array. my function is as below. its difficult to demonstrate whole process in the code. therefore pls check bellow function.

```
           $scope.showTab = [];
           $scope.goToTabContent = function(id){
                $scope.currentId = id;
                $scope.reportTab.push(id);    
            };
currently I can insert duplicate value into 'report Tab' array.
ex: [9,9].

 I need to push only unique values. how I do it. can u help me.
```

Comment: If it has to be an array then the only way to avoid duplicates is to not add a value to the array that is already in it. Which means scanning the array first. (Which is maybe not very efficient, in which case you may want a different data structure or algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.goToTabContent = function(id){
    $scope.currentId = id;
    //check if id is not present in $scope.reportTab array and push the id
    if($scope.reportTab.indexOf(id) < 0){
      $scope.reportTab.push(id);    
    }
};
```

You can use the  *[Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)* or angularjs has built in jquery lite , so you can also use *[jQuery.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)* if you want to rely on jquery

```
if ($.inArray(id,$scope.reportTab)==-1) $scope.reportTab.push(id);
```